# Creating a method which executes Automatically after a specified time in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I have created a method in controller where i have used action mailer for sending email.I want that method to be executed after every 12 am at night and email to be send to the person who is having a birthday on that day.

Comment: Can you please post the steps & code you did so far ?

Answer (score 1):

Create rake task under lib folder.And add whenever gem to execute rake task at every 12 am.

Comment: i have done this but email is not going.Every time i need to run rake command only at that time email goes.

Comment: You have to set cron job. If you use heroku then add schedular addon and add rake task under it.

Answer (score 0):

In lib folder
create a class

```
class Notification
  def self.send_greetings
    # give here your own logic to find users with birthday
    users = User.all
    users.each do |user|
      UsersMailer.weekly_mail(u.email).deliver
    end
  end
end
```

setup whenever gem

```
every :day, :at => '12:00am' do
  runner "Notification.send_greetings", :environment => 'development',   :output => 'log/cron.log' 
end
```

Comment: thanks for your  response but will you pls guide me,where i have to write this  every :day, :at => '12:00am' do
  runner "Notification.send_greetings", :environment => 'development',   :output => 'log/cron.log' 
end      ,and will it needed to run this command mnually or it will run automatically at every 12 am if i write the proper logic in mailer??????????

Comment: please use **whenever gem** [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever)

Comment: [Use This link to watch about whenever](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_I3gq06M6B0)

Comment: i need to add it to lib/task folder??

Comment: create in `lib` folder

Comment: okkkkkk.......and will this method be run automatically at every 12 am if i specify......or i need to run it manually....???? i just need to know............

Comment: rply @mihir kumar thakur

Comment: Whenever add task to **cron job** . Cron job will automatically run on time specified. You don't need to run it manually. [learn more about cron job](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html)

Comment: ok u mean to say that whenever gem act as cron command in linux and it will automatically run at a specified time.But does it run on Rails 4???

Comment: in my cron.log file
      
bundler: not executable: bin/rails  is written  but still email is not going,i have written this in my schedule.rb file   every :thursday, :at => '11:02am' do  
   runner "InterviewSchedule.sample_email.deliver", :environment => 'development',   :output => 'log/cron.log' 
 end